# Javascript redirection to other page not working

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I am working on a WordPress site where am using contact form 7 plugin. Now I want to redirect the page to thank you page and append form id with URL. But every time it redirects to the home page. am using wpcf7mailsent DOM event.

I have searched around for several hours. I have used the following redirection methods

```
window.location("/thankyou?submission="+formID);
document.location = 'https://example.com/thankyou'+formID;
document.location.href = '/thankyou?submission='+formID;
window.location.assign('https://example.com/thankyou'+formID);
window.location.replace('https://example.com/thankyou'+formID);
window.location.replace('https://example.com/thankyou'+formID);
jQuery(location).attr('href','example.com/thankyou'+formID);
```

Here is my code

```
var nr_wpcf7Elm = document.querySelector( '.wpcf7' );

nr_wpcf7Elm.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
    var inputs = event.detail.inputs;
    var formID = event.detail.contactFormId;
    window.location.href = '/thankyou?submission='+formID;
}, false );
```

I need to redirect the user to a thank you page and I want URL with form ID.

Comment: It is likely that this issue is occurring because formID is undefined.

Comment: formID is defined here var formID = event.detail.contactFormId;  and it holds value

Comment: It is declared and set, but it is most likely undefined. Please console.log() it and tell us the result.

Comment: console showing value

Comment: Just get it all out first: var linkText = '/thankyou?submission='+formID;
console.log(linkText);

Comment: If all you wanna do is to redirect to a page, and add a value from the form, you could look into this : https://wordpress.org/plugins/wpcf7-redirect/

Comment: and just select to pass a specific field from the form

Comment: You're sure that event is getting fired?  Does the address bar update?  I can't wrap my head around why this would not be working unless the event isn't getting fired.

Comment: event is getting fired thats why it is redirecting to home page but not to that specific url.

Comment: @Christian am getting correct url in console

Comment: Add this line,   window.location.href = '/thankyou?submission='+formID;

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `wpcf7submit` event.

```
var nr_wpcf7Elm = document.querySelector( '.wpcf7' );

nr_wpcf7Elm.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsubmit', function( event ) {
    var inputs = event.detail.inputs;
    var formID = event.detail.contactFormId;
    window.location.href = '/thankyou?submission='+formID;
}, false );
```

Comment: I need it to run on wpcf7mailsent. not on wpcf7mailsubmit